# Password validation for resetting password

Tags: users, registration, validation, password

I have the following code to further validate passwords when creating/registering an account which is working fine.

However, when trying to use this same validation for resetting a password I am not getting any errors back?

Can anyone point me in the right direction...?

```
public function onBeforeSetPassword(Event $event)
{
    $user = $event->params['user'];
    $password = $event->params['password'];

    if (mb_strlen($password) < 8)
    {
        $user->addError('password', 'Sorry but your password must be at least 8 characters.');
        $event->performAction = false;
    }

    if (!preg_match('/(\d.*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*\d)/', $password))
    {
        $user->addError('password', 'Sorry but your password must contain at least one uppercase letter and one number.');
        $event->performAction = false;
    }
}
```

On the template:

```
{% if account is defined and account.getErrors('password') %}
    {% include '_includes/formError' with { error : account.getErrors('password')|join('<br>') } %}
{% endif %}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in the context of a front-end registered user or a CP registered one? Also, if you `Craft::log()` in there, is your method even being hit in the reset password scenario?

Comment: FWIW, I checked and the `onBeforeSetPassword` event does seem to fire when passwords are reset. You can confirm this yourself by adding `MyPluginHandlePlugin::log("Setting password...");` to your event handler (obviously, replace `MyPluginHandle` with the real handle for your plugin), and then open up your plugin's log file at `/craft/storage/runtime/logs/mypluginhandle.log`, after resetting a password. If the event does indeed fire, there's something else amiss with your code somewhere.

Comment: @BradBell this is on a front end user (actually customers for commerce) form. I will try what Mats has suggest to see if firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't validating againts the field newPassword, only validating against password. Hence why I wasn't getting any feedback. Duplicating the validation for newPassword seems to have resolved this.